# Is there a word for the material that constitutes all physical being?

Tags: atomic-physics, terminology, continuum-mechanics

Is there a word to describe the material that, no matter how many divisions are made upon it, maintains all of its qualities?

Note that I speak not of matter. Though matter was the first thing that came to mind, it is said to be composed of atoms, and atoms in turn are said to be composed of smaller, more fundamental constituents. So by logic, matter cannot be it.

What then, is the correct word to use?

Comment: If you can divide it it doesn't maintain its cohesion. (So no.)
Probably you want to re-word the question slightly.
If you can;t change it at all it is immutable, then you cannot divide it.

Comment: Yes, true, but such things are mathematical properties, I speak of physical things.

Comment: I think you'll be very grateful if you ever cross a bridge, for example, that it's ability to resist division is a physical property.
It's hard to be helpful if the terminology is not conventional or is inaccurate conventional. Possible I could suggest you might be looking for energy, given matter is energy E=mc^2.

Comment: Well, it may be able to resist division under normal circumstances, but it is by no means indivisible... Anyway, let us say you take an apple, and divide it, it maintains it's physical properties, it has the same smell, taste, touch etc, and this is quite independent of its mathematical properties, it has been halved, yes, but it has not affected it's physical properties therein.

Comment: Note that of course, there are a few caveats you may have noticed, but I hope the analogy serves its purpose.

Comment: I don't want to get into a debate about what you choose to call physical or mathematical. I'll interpret from my perspective that by mathematical you are intending geometric.
 
This suggests to me the word homogenous "the same throughout" might be of use. Final offer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The proper term is "continuum" and the general study of its motion is "continuum mechanics," usually used to understand fluids and plasmas.

Of course, such a model is always approximate because our universe **is** made up of lumps at its smallest; [you can see them for example here](https://www.research.ibm.com/articles/madewithatoms.shtml). Quantum mechanics makes it possible to describe discrete particles with continuous functions, but we still speak of things like a "quantum electron field," still thinking about the electrons as discrete excitations in the field.

Comment: Hey CR Drost, thanks for your answer. I think I see what you mean. So if my understanding is correct, even if you have this atom which cannot be broken down, it still mathematically makes sense to try and do so, even if it's physically impossible. But because it cannot be broken down, we say that it's a continuum, rather than the aggregation of smaller parts?

Comment: -1 for "the universe **is** made up of lumps at its smallest". As far as we understand QFT, that's not really true in any way I can think of. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Erm, not that I really care but I think you just -1'd me when you meant CR Drost (not that I think he deserves one, or rather minus one, just sayin...)

Comment: @DanielSank Are you saying that because you feel that the question is about something more fundamental than continuum mechanics?

Comment: @user108262 No, I'm saying that the word you're looking for is a "continuum", describing something which is infinitely divisible. However the "continuum mechanics" that we use to describe the world, does not work well at atomic scales: because atoms are not able to be broken down further without losing their distinct nature.

Comment: @user108262 Nope, I -1'd CR Drost's answer. I don't know why you think I -1'd you.

Comment: @DanielSank QFT is a mathematical model. Experimentally we measure "lumps" if by "lumps" one means "quanta of energy". The statement is OK imo

Comment: @annav quanta of energy and spatial lumps seem like very different ideas to me.

Comment: Quantum fields are not too different than electromagnetic fields in their existence. And they are quantized so excitations come in lumps of energy, and per the uncertainty principle they are also everywhere, and through measurement we decohere them and can localize them. That's just the way quantum theory is, counterintuitive but Not a model, just the truth. We test for them in similar ways.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's quantum fields and they do excitation which are called particles. Quantum fields are everywhere in spacetime. The other part is the spacetime itself which is actually also a dynamic entity. How those two merge together into one unified entity is the ultimate goal of physics, and is awaiting a unified theory which for the moment is thought would need to be a quantum gravity theory. There are some proposed theories, like string theory, but it's all under active study